Not able to map my root domain under CloudScale - Domain Mappings in a Zoho Catalyst project
I'm facing trouble with my CNAME and domain mapping for my Catalyst application while trying to map my domain {x}.com
When I enter {x}.com in step 1 of domain mapping in Catalyst console, I am getting the CNAME entry hostname as <BLANK_VALUE>. I am not sure on what the host name should be added in my DNS provider console.

Currently, you might not be able to map your parent domain {x}.com with a Catalyst application. Hence, provide a domain with a subdomain such as www.{x}.com in Step 1 of domain mapping.
Now, in Step 2, you will be provided to map 2 CNAME entries i.e.
(1) Add a CNAME entry with hostname as your subdomain (www) pointing to catalyst.cs.zohohost.com and
(2) Add another CNAME entry with the hostname as {catalyst_generated_hash_key}.subdomain pointing to catalyst.cs.zohohost.com. You need to add 2 CNAME entries in your DNS provider console, shown in Step 2 of Catalyst.
The CNAME values would look like this:
CNAME                                             value
www                                               catalyst.cs.zohohost.com
{your_hash_key}.www                               catalyst.cs.zohohost.com

Once you have added the above 2 CNAME entries in your DNS provider console, wait for a few minutes and then click on Verify in Step 2 of domain mappings in Catalyst. You will be moved to Step 3. You will be notified when the Catalyst team has applied the group SSL.
